# RequireJS 2.0 - Defining my Backbone.Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, undefined, requirejs

I'm currently trying RequireJS 2.0 and consequently have to change some code.
Here's my `main.js`, launched with `data-main` in my `index.phtml`.

**EDIT** : Forgot project structure, can be useful :)

```
->public

 -> css
 -> js
 app.js
 facade.js
 main.js
 router.js
 ...
  -> collections
  -> libs

   -> backbone
   -> jquery
   -> json2
   -> plugins
   -> require
   -> underscore

 -> templates
...


// Filename: main.js

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// There usage will become more apparent futher along in the tutorial.

require.config({
    //Here baseUrl = /js (Loaded in data-main in logged.phtml)
    // 3rd party script alias names (Easier to type "jquery" than "libs/jquery-1.7.2.min")
    paths: {
        jQuery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        Underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
        Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
        JSON: 'libs/json2/json2',
        templates: '../templates'
    },

    // Sets the configuration for your third party scripts that are not AMD compatible
    shim: {
        'libs/plugins/bootstrap-min': ['jQuery'],
        'libs/plugins/jquery.cookies.min': ['jQuery'],
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'JSON': {
            exports: 'JSON'
        },
        'Underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'Backbone': {
            deps: ['Underscore', 'jQuery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'  // attaches "Backbone" to the window object
        }
    }
});

define([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app',
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'JSON'
], function(App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
});
```

I tried to add 'router' to this file with its dependencies but nothing has changed, so I assumed it was useless.

And here's the app.js loaded when calling App:

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'JSON',
    'router', // Request router.js
    'i18n!nls/langs',
    'facade',
    //'order!libs/plugins/jquery.backstretch.min'
    //'libs/plugins/backbone.validation.min'
], function($, _, Backbone, JSON, Router, langs, facade) {
var initialize = ...
...
...
return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Here's the problem, in my `router.js` definition, I used a `console.log` and it showed me that it was returning the right object.

But when I call `router` in my `app.js`, `router` stays undefined.
I probably made a mistake but I can't find it.

**EDIT :** Added the `router.js` code

```
require([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'JSON',
    'facade',
    'models/UserModel',
    'libs/plugins/jquery.cookies.min'
], function($, _, Backbone, JSON, facade, User, cookies){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
...
    });

    var app_router = new AppRouter;
        // Start Backbone history a neccesary step for bookmarkable URL's
        Backbone.history.start();
    return app_router;
});
```

Comment: Is router.js defining an AMD module properly?

Comment: Well, what you said made me think a little, and I checked my `router.js`, there was a `require` instead of a `define` so it would not return me an AMD module... Make an answer so I can accept it ;) ! Thanks
(I edited with `router.js` + the original error so you can point it out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `router.js` file isn't defining an AMD module properly. You need to use `define`, not `require`.

Comment: I wasted my 2 hours just for this reason... Thanks your answer was straight to point! +1